# Null/blank in last column when use datatools

Tags: datatool

i use datatools to create pdf
But last column display Null or blank

My minimal coding:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fileabc.tex}
AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD|
1|TNMT\_100|NT|E1|
2|TNMT\_109|NT|EE|
3|TNMT\_210|AT|E|
4|TNMT\_340|NT|E30|
5|TNMT\_12|AT|E31|
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{fileabc}{fileabc.tex}



\newcommand{\printCCCCoding}[1]{%
 \par

 \DTLforeach*
 [\DTLiseq{\CCCCoding}{#1}]%
 {fileabc}% Database
 {\CCCCoding=CCC,\AAACoding=AAA, \BBBCoding=BBB,\DDDCoding=\DDD}{%
 \noindent \CCCCoding \hspace{0.1cm} 2 \AAACoding \hspace{0.1cm}  3 \BBBCoding \hspace{0.1cm} 4 \DDD \par
  }% 
}

\begin{document}


\DTLdisplaydb{fileabc}
%\newpage
\\
\printCCCCoding{NT}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your DDD column in `\printCCCCoding` is incorrect. It should be similar to the other columns:

```
\newcommand{\printCCCCoding}[1]{%
 \par

 \DTLforeach*
 [\DTLiseq{\CCCCoding}{#1}]%
 {fileabc}% Database
 {\CCCCoding=CCC,\AAACoding=AAA, \BBBCoding=BBB,\DDDCoding=DDD}{%
 \noindent \CCCCoding \hspace{0.1cm} 2 \AAACoding \hspace{0.1cm}  3 \BBBCoding \hspace{0.1cm} 4 \DDDCoding \par
  }% 
}
```

Note the `\DDDCoding=DDD` instead of the original `\DDDCoding=\DDD` and correspondingly `\DDDCoding` in the next line.

Result:

[image]